# Regex - Remove space chars whenever there are more than one in succession, but exclude all lines commented out

Tags: regex, boost

Let's say I have a few lines as follows:

```
01090   C   -------CALCULATION OF SOMETHING--
01100   "SOME.VARIABLE"   =  "SOME.OTHER.VARIABLE" + 2
01110   IF("SOME.VARIABLE" .NE.  "SOME.VALUE")  THEN   ON("SOME.MACHINE")
```

I would like to go through the program and remove all of the space characters that have more than one in succession.  For example, line 01100 has three (3) space characters before the "=" and two (2) after.  In line 01110, there are several different locations with more than 1 consecutive space char.
I would like to replace them with just a single space char.  I do NOT want to remove/alter the spaces that are contained within the commented line 01090.

All lines begin with 5 digits, all lines have a tab following the line number, and only commented lines have a "C" or a "c" that denotes them as commented out.

I am using Sublime3, and boost regex.  I have tried things like:

```
(?!\t[Cc] )[ ]{2,}
(?!\t[Cc])[ ]{2,}
```

I can't seem to determine how to negate an entire line without also capturing an entire line.

I tried putting a caret in the beginning as well, but that didn't seem to help.

Basically, if the line has a "TAB" followed by a "c" or a "C", then ignore the entire thing.  Otherwise, any two or more consecutive space chars are located and replaced with a single space char.

EDIT

--------- solution ---------

Thanks to the input from Wiktor and The fourth bird, I was able to determine the solution.  Many thanks to both.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
^\d+\t[cC].*\K|[ ]{2,}
```

I also determined that should there be extra spaces at the end of a line, I might want to ignore those as well so I can remove them completely with a different regex search.  The final product looks like this:

```
^\d+\t[cC].*\K|[ ]*\n\K|[ ]{2,}
```

If I had not been limited by the engine of boost or PCRE, I believe one of my previous failed attempts would actually work.  I'll include that here in the event it helps someone else.  It can't be used in boost or PCRE because they don't support infinite lookbehinds:

```
(?<!\t[cC].*)[ ]{2,}
```

Comment: I think you want `^\d+\tC\h.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\p{Zs}{2,}` and replace with a space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks you for the quick reply.  When I run your example, I get an error that the escape sequence was neither a valid property nor a valid character class name.  What I think I understood from this is that you are essentially just throwing out the match at that point.  I also ran into the issue that the engine doesn't support unicode properties, which is the {Zs} portion.

Comment: Sorry, but Boost supports `\p{Zs}`. As for SKIP-FAIL, you are right. Where exactly are you performing this cleanup? Well, you might try `(?<!^\d+\tC\b.*)[ \t]{2,}`, too.

Comment: Aha, so you want `^\d+\tC.*\K|( ){2,}` and replace with `$1`?

Comment: I'm using Sublime3 text editor.  I also checked \p{Zs} with regex buddy, and it said it doesn't support it either.  I'm not sure where the problem lays, but neither would accept it.  Regardless, you helped me get to the finish line, and I appreciate it!

Comment: Well, I installed the latest SublimeText and `^\d+\tC\h.*\K|(\h){2,}` > `$1` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

```
^\d{5}\t[cC] .*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h{2,}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{5}\t` Match 5 digits and a tab
- `[cC]`  Match either `c` or `C` and a space
- `.*$` Match the rest of the line
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `\h{2,}` Match 2 or more horizontal whitespace chars

In the replacement use a single space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Md77T7/1)

As solved by the OP, a shortened version using `\K` and matching 2 or more spaces:

```
^\d+\tC.*\K|[ ]{2,}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1 or more digits
- `\tC` Match a tab and a `C` char
- `.*\K` Match the rest of the line and clear the match buffer
- `|` Or
- `[ ]{2,}` Match 2 or more spaces (square brackets are only for visibility and not necessary)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN2Zyf/1)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. While the result is much the same as Wiktor's, above, I was able to replace the SKIP and FAIL with just a \K (which I believe accomplishes the same feat). Here's what I came up with that I believe solves the problem: ^\d+\t[cC].*\K|[ ]{2,} As you see, I was concerned that the horiz white space \h might capture something unwanted, so I specified further by including only the space character in the character class. VERY big thank you to both you and Wiktor. I have much to learn, so thank you for sharing your common approach and and leading me to the solution.

Comment: @BASTech In this case that would lead to the same result yes. Let me add that as a second solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehid to your regex. Try something like this.

```
(?<![Cc])\s{3,}(?![Cc])
```

Comment: When I ran this, it still selected all whitespace chars of three or more in succession, regardless of whether or not the line began with the "C" comment delimiter.  Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem, but I thank you for taking the time to try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you might actually be preparing to parse this language. Parsers aren't often convenient using regular expressions.

Also, you didn't ask but in this case the transformation could be in-place (since the output is shorter than the input, or of equal length).

I'd suggest a PEG grammar like this (using Boost Spirit):

```
template <typename In, typename Out>
Out compress_whitespace(In f, In l, Out out) {
    auto copy = [&out](auto& ctx) {
        struct Append {
            static void call(Out& out, char ch) { *out++ = ch; }
            static void call(Out& out, boost::iterator_range<In> raw) {
                for (auto ch : raw) *out++ = ch; }
        };

        Append::call(out, _attr(ctx));
    };

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto prefix  = raw[uint_ >> "   "][copy];
    auto comment = raw["C " >> *(char_ - eol)][copy];
    auto code_ch = omit[+blank] >> attr(' ')[copy] | (char_ - eol)[copy];
    auto line    = prefix >> (comment | *code_ch);
    auto newline = raw[eol][copy];

    parse(f, l, -line % newline);
    return out;
}
```

To disallow empty lines:

```
    parse(f, l, line % newline);
```

To throw at incomplete/invalid input change the `parse` line:

```
    parse(f, l, expect[line % newline >> *newline >> eoi]);
```

**[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bQw6VaWXpCoxHsHf)**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ostreambuf_iterator out(std::cout);

    for (std::string file : std::vector(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        std::ifstream s(file, std::ios::binary);
        std::string const program(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{s}, {});

        compress_whitespace(begin(program), end(program), out);
    }
}
```

Output using `vim -d input.txt  <(./sotest input.txt)`:

[image]

### BONUS: In place processing

Since we know the output will be same length or less, you can afford to process inplace:

```
    std::string program = R"~(
01090   C   -------CALCULATION OF SOMETHING--
01100   "SOME.VARIABLE"   =  "SOME.OTHER.VARIABLE" + 2
01110   IF("SOME.VARIABLE" .NE.  "SOME.VALUE")  THEN   ON("SOME.MACHINE"))~";

    auto b = begin(program), e = end(program),
         new_e = compress_whitespace(b, e, b);

    std::cout << "Shorter by " << (e - new_e) << " chars\n";
    program.erase(new_e, e);

    std::cout << program << "\n";
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba0f5b99ac8ab87a)**, printing:

```
Shorter by 7 chars

01090   C   -------CALCULATION OF SOMETHING--
01100   "SOME.VARIABLE" = "SOME.OTHER.VARIABLE" + 2
01110   IF("SOME.VARIABLE" .NE. "SOME.VALUE") THEN ON("SOME.MACHINE")
```